# Compiling/Running Java files in Terminal

Tags: java, macos, command-line, terminal

I'm attempting to run a file that calls multiple files, but I'm getting some errors.

Inside the current directory called **day4Measurement**, I have 13 files: BuggyMeasurement.java, BuggyMeasurement01.java, BuggyMeasurement02.java, BuggyMeasurement03.java, BuggyMeasurement04.java...BuggyMeasurement10.java, MeasurementTest.java, and Measurement.java.

**Measurement.java** contains the *main()* and calls all the other files.

Here's the *main()*:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    JUnitCore tester = new JUnitCore();
    String s = "Failed to detect: ";
    int count = 0;
    String [] tests = {"toString prints reverse inches then feet", // 01
        "plus modifies this", // 02
        "minus modifies this", // 03
        "multiple modifies this", // 04
        "plus incorrect roll over", // 05
        "minus incorrect roll over", // 06
        "multiple incorrect roll over", // 07
        "plus incorrect non-roll over", // 08
        "minus incorrect non-roll over", // 09
        "multiple incorrect non-roll over", // 10
        "CORRRRECTTT!!!"
    };
    for (int i = 1; i < tests.length + 1; i++){
        testRound = i;
        System.out.println("Running: " + tests[i-1]);
        TestRunner.run(day4Measurement.MeasurementTest.class);
        Result temp = tester.run(day4Measurement.MeasurementTest.class);
        if (temp.wasSuccessful()) {
            s += tests[i-1] + "; ";
            count++;
        }

    }

    System.out.print(10-(count-1)*0.5 + " ");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

In the Mac Terminal, I run

```
javac Measurement.java
```

and I get issues. Here's what I get:

[image]
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't post images of text, post the text itself.

Comment: Note that idiomatic for loops are more like: `for (int i=0; i<foo.length; i++) { bar(foo[i]); }`. Arrays are zero-indexed and the sooner you get used to that, the easier your code will be for others to read -- and you'll more easily understand everyone else's code, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have all the files in a directory (they may be in subdirectories - as long as they are all inside some shared directory), let's call it dir, use the following:

```
javac -classpath dir Measurement.java
```

Assuming that you are running the command from the same directory that Measurement.java is in.  If not, and either way you are safer this way, make it an explicit path to both dir and Measurement.java, such as:

```
javac -classpath /home/yourusername/dir /home/yourusername/dir/Measurement.java
```

This says to the java compiler "I want to compile Measurement.java, here's where it is, and here's where you can find all the class and/or source files that it needs."  It will then compile only the files referred to by Measurement.java, so you don't need to worry about accidentally compiling all of your java files ever.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check would be to make sure your directory structure for those files mirrors the package structure. For example, if package for class ABC is com.foo, then your ABC.java file should live in com/foo folder.

Answer (score 0):

Compile all the files with javac *.java

Comment: @cmastudios: If i'm reading it correctly, he's asking whether `javac` knows enough to see that `BuggyMeasurement01.java` is in its list of stuff to compile, and won't go searching for it.  Or rather, whether it *doesn't* know enough, meaning the files have to be compiled in order somehow.