# CSV to tab delimited java in command line

Tags: java, csv, delimited

Updated Code.  This program should take the CSV file and separate it into TSV files by school,but I am not getting it to work.  I am getting it to create the files correctly, but only one has any data in it...

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>{

    public int id = 0;
    public String name = "";
    public String school = "";


    public Student(int id, String name, String school){

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.school = school;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return id+"\t"+name+"\t"+school;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        return  this.school.compareTo(o.school);
    }
}

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;


public class ReadCSV {

    public static String CSV_FILE_PATH = "/Users/eringray/Desktop/csvtotab/input.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CSV_FILE_PATH));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(CSV_FILE_PATH + ".tsv"));

            ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();

            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split(",");

                if(values.length == 3) {
                    String idAsString = values[0];
                    String name = values[1];
                    String school = values[2];

                    int id = Integer.parseInt(idAsString);

                    Student s = new Student(id, name, school);

                    list.add(s);
                }
            }

            Collections.sort(list);

            String currentSchool = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                Student stu = list.get(i);
                if(currentSchool != stu.school){
                  currentSchool = stu.school; 
                  bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(CSV_FILE_PATH + stu.school + ".tsv"));
              }

              String lineText = stu.toString();
              bw.write(lineText);
              bw.newLine();
            }

            br.close();
            bw.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to use java for this, using the linux utility `tr` is quicker as it can do `tr ',' '\t'` to replace them really quick

Comment: yeah, I need to use java, this is an assignment I'm working on. thanks!

Comment: do you allready have some code? please post it, if so.
What you need, is the replace function of the string class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)

Comment: I feel like I would need something like this, but am unsure of how to change the variables to make it do what I want to on different files.
http://www.coderanch.com/t/592700/java/java/Code-critique-CSV-Tab-delimited

Comment: read my answer, but if you dont have to sort the list by school, but only replace the , by tabs, you can read the file (bufferedreader) line by line, use the replace method on the line (to replace , by \t) and write the output line in a new file (bufferedwriter). for more details, read my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing, you have to do is reading the input file.
I think, you need to read it line by line (depends on file structure).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Next step is to seperate the data and sort it by school (if i understood your question well).

For this you have to split the data and create a class to store the information:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

```
public Class Student{
   public String name = "";
   ....

   public Student(String name, String school, ...){}
}
```

When you have created a Student  object for each student in the list, you have  to sort the students by school:

You could implement compareable and use Collection.sort().

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Last thing is to print the output, for this you have to override the toString method of the student class:

```
public String toString(){
   return this.id+"\t"+this.name+"\t"+this.school;
}
```

and iterate throug the list  of your students and call the toString method:

```
System.out.println(students.get(i).toString());
```

**EDIT:**

If you need the output in a file and not in the console, just use a [fileoutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) and a [bufferedwriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) to print the output of the toString method in a file.

Comment: Awesome!  That is exactly what I was looking for!  I'll give that a shot and may return with a few small questions.  Thanks again!

Comment: I've been working on this over the weekend but have been struggling.  I've added what I have so far to my original post. For the next step, am I supposed to create a new java class file?  How could I get that to work with my original code?  Sorry for the novice questions, I just started learning java last week, so I am quite behind!

Comment: the assignment is to do it in a text editor, but I don't really understand how to do it that way

Comment: ok, i will write you same code and explanaition (should take about 10 mins)

Comment: @Rassisland so, i have written some code, with comments. At first, create a folder, for your code, then create to text files and name them: Person.java and Test35.java ---- you can change the names, but then you should also change the class names. The code is here: http://pastebin.com/aYJj1AQk  and http://pastebin.com/avC7vqzx The last think you need, is to change path to your file and then compile the whole think: go on commandline into the folder, with your java files and do `javac *.java` to compile all the files and `java Test35` to run the main method of the programm.

Comment: Wow!  This is amazing!  Thank you so much for the help!  I'll go through this and let you know if I have any more questions.  Thanks again though, I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: this is great!  The only issue I'm getting is when I try to compile the Test35.java file, all the references to "Person" are showing errors.  Maybe I did something incorrect?  Let me know if you have any ideas, if not, I can figure it out!  You've helped a lot already!  THanks again!

Comment: @Rassisland Do you have both of your files in the same directory? Are you compiling both files at same time? Are your files named properly (Test35.java and Person.java)? http://s14.postimg.org/nblnpuwq9/so2.png

Comment: I am using a mac, would that make a difference?  Everything is in the same directory.  I will try again today after work.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: should work anyway ... if not, try defining a classpath http://stackoverflow.com/a/11236730/5806393

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/t4owmyrtp/ I'm getting these errors when I try to compile both .java files at the same time.  Let me know if you see anything I'm doing wrong!

Comment: @Rassisland hmm, that is system related ... try to first compile person, then Test35 --- if that dont work, user classpath (see link in my last comment)

Comment: Hmmm, the classpath thing doesn't seem to help; I'll keep messing around with it!  I appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi Jarlik! I got everything working, but have a question. Is there any way to create a new tab delimited file for each school? Could I just use an if else statement by school?

Comment: @Rassisland its easy possible :) just change the output method. before the for loop (with `bw.write`) add a String curSchool = ""; and inide the loop an if statement (`if(curSchool != list.get(i).school ){curSchool = list.get(i).school; bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pathToFile+list.get(i).school+".tsv"));}`) and after this if statement, just use the code, that is allready there (bw.write(...); bw.newLine();

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I've updated my original code, based off the code you created, with some changes to make it a little easier for me to follow.  I tried implementing your suggestion, and it does create the files I was hoping to, but all but one of the files is now empty... Any ideas?